# How to check cursor(dbh) is active or not for sybase connection in python

Tags: cursor, sybase, dbconnection

In db2 we have
`import ibm_db import active` to check whether the cursor(dbh) is active or not
I am looking for the similar module in **sybase**

Answer (score 0):

the is no active methode in sybase module. we need to run a query (select 1  ) and catch  the exception if there is an error.

Comment: sys.dummy doesn't exist in sybase (at least in ASE) - better to just do a 'select 1' instead.

Comment: your right, SYS.DUMMY exist only in sybaseIQ